# Resolve ambigus function call when the only difference is a parameter passed by reference or by copy

Tags: c++

Say I have a class implementing these two methods :

```
void foo(const int a);
void foo(const int & a);
```

How do I resolve ambiguous call like :

```
int bar = 42;
foo(bar);
```

#### EDIT

Both methods are virtual pure inherited from two different parents, doing different things. I would like to have the ability to choose one at call.

Bigger code example :

```
class B{
  virtual void foo(const int a) = 0;
};

class C{
  virtual void foo(const int & a) = 0;
};

class A : public B, public C{
  void foo(const int a){
    // do something
  }
  void foo(const int & a){
    // do something else
  }
};

int main(){
  A a;
  int bar = 42;
  a.foo(bar);
}
```

`B` and `C` class are not write by me in my real case, but I have to use these.

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question, do you want to know how this case would be resolved or you want it to work? If first it wont be if the second then you should specify criteria.

Comment: Change the name of either the B::foo, or the C::foo.  Note that in B::foo, the `const int` parameter, the `const` is not part of the signature and is irrelevant to callers.

Comment: I can't modify the C or B code. And `const` is used to make it mandatory to not modify the value passed when implementing the method.

Comment: You're asking the impossible... But probably this is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/): What do you **really** want to achieve. Give more background.

Comment: @JHBonarius lot's of fun here :-) but I work with code of others and try to minimize the amount of re-writing, I repeat : what I want to achieve is, starting to this, be able to choose which method will be called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual solution to this kind of problem is to use a pair of intermediate classes to rename those functions.

```
struct intermediate1 : base1 {
    virtual void f(int x) = 0;
    void foo(int x} { f(x); }
};

struct intermediate2 : base2 {
    virtual void g(const int& x) = 0;
    void foo(const int& x} { g(x); }
};
```

Now your class can be derived from the two intermediate classes instead of the two original base classes, and your code can override `f(whatever)` and `g(whatever)` and call them, rather than the conflicting `foo` versions.

If you like decorating functions you could mark both of those versions of `foo` as `final`.

Comment: Seems dirty but do the job.

Comment: @Welgriv -- unfortunately, it just sunk in that this doesn't deal with the virtual-ness of the two versions of `foo`. I've rewritten the answer to fix that; if it doesn't address your problem, feel free to withdraw your acceptance. (In general, you should wait a day or so before accepting an answer, in case someone comes up with a better one).

Answer (score 0):

The c++11 way is to use rvalue ref for the 1st overload:

```
  void foo(int&& rvalue);
  void foo(int& lvalue);
```

read more on rvalue ref at:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference

For the multiple-inheritance issue:

```
 struct D:C{
     virtual void foo(int&&, std::nullptr_t)=0;
 private:
     void foo(int v) final { return foo(std::move(v),nullptr); };
 };
 
 struct A:B,D{
    void foo(int&&, std::nullptr_t=nullptr) override;
    void foo(int& ) override;
 };
```

Comment: Why did you make this a community wiki? No problem with that, I'm just curious :)

Comment: Rvalue reference. If you dont like it, I dont insist.

Comment: I get your point but in my case I can't do any hypothesis over the type of the parameter given at the call.

Comment: So you have an issue with multiple inheritance. Wrap the `B` class in a decorator derived class from which `A` will be derived. But further inheritance from A will be complicated: the wrapper class must make foo a `final` `override` forwarding to a distinct virtual function that `A` and children will `override`.